# Where do I insert progress bar code into a nested loop?

Tags: r

I have a nested 'for' loop in R, which runs over a large data frame (over 80,000 obvs of over 6000 variables) and assigns a value to a new column based on values in the other variables.

Due to the data frame size, and the fact I am testing multiple edits to the loops, I'd like to insert a progress bar so I have more of an idea how long runs might take.

So far I've tried this:

```
# create an example dataset
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
capital1 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital2 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital3 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital4 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital5 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital6 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital7 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital8 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital9 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))
capital10 <- replicate(1,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE))

data <- data.frame(id, capital1, capital2, capital3, capital4,
capital5, capital6, capital7, capital8, capital9, capital10)

# create new column to populate with results of loop
nrows<-length(data[,1])
AFT<-rep("N_A",nrows)

# set up progress bar for loop
total <- nrows
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = length(total), style = 3)

# for loop
for (i in c(1:nrows)) { 

    Sys.sleep(.1)

    # Mask out waterbodies and dense artifical (urban) areas
    if (data$capital1[i]>70) {
        AFT[i]<-'water.urban'} 

    if (data$capital2[i]>70) {
        AFT[i]<-'water.urban'} 

    if (data$capital3[i]+data$capital4[i]>=60){
        AFT[i]<-'multi.mixed'}
    if (data$capital4[i]>70) {
        AFT[i]<-'multi.nb'}

    # etc. (10+ more loops assigning different AFTs)

    # print progress as loop runs
    cat("\r", i, "of", 10, "\r") 
    flush.console()

}
```

At the moment the code runs, but the progress bar seems to complete straight away, while the actual process carries on running. I assume I'm not putting the progress bar code in the right place in the loop?

Comment: Your code as provided will not run. First you are missing a `}` on the 'multi.mixed' line.  Also, your `cat` statement at the end refers to a variable called `j` which is not in your code.

Comment: @G5W Thanks, I've now edited the code to take account of your comments. This now runs for me on the example code, but when run on my actual data it slows down the process considerably compared to running without the progress bar i.e. takes est. up to an hour not under 20 seconds

Answer (score 2):

by typing `?txtProgressBar` you will be directed to the help file for the function. Here you will see two other functions `getTxtProgressBar` and `setTxtProgressBar`. As their name indicates, these can be used to obtain and set the current progress on any instantiated progressbar.

For your example try adding `setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)` at the spot within your for loop, where you wish to update the progress. The chosen spot can be anywhere, dependant on when and how often you wish to show the progress. For example, as your particular example the progress bar has a max value that is also used while iterating `i`, updating the progress bar could be achieved at the start of the for loop as below.

```
for (i in c(1:nrows)) { 
  setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
  ...
}
close(pb)
```

Note how i use `close(pb)` after the loop, to turn off the progress bar.

Comment: Why not write an actual answer showing how it works? Otherwise this is almost similar to just leaving a comment.

Comment: Hello Nelson. Burton seemed experienced enough for the previous answer to be self explanatory. However i have updated the answer hopefully improving it slightly.

Comment: Well, someone else may pick interest in the question and a detailed explanation while good is always better with some examples.

Comment: agreed. Thank you for noting such that i noted the slightly lacking answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks both. So could I insert more than one 'setTxtProgressBar(pb,i)' after each section of the loop?

Comment: Hello Burton. The second answer seems more to what you were looking for. For future reference, yes you can set/get the value of the progress bar at any point, even multiple times during any program.  It only requires adjusting the max and min value initially and being observant of which value you set the progressbar to. 
For large calculations a progress bar can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to iterate over 80,000 rows with a `for` loop, use the power of R's vectorized capabilities.  You could select which values of AFT to update using the `which` function.  The `which` function returns a vector of the indices where the comparison is TRUE.   This will provide a 1000x performance improvement over your for loop, thus making the progress bar obsolete.

For example your assignments would be something like:

```
AFT[which(data$capital1>70)] <-'water.urban'
AFT[which(data$capital2>70)] <-'water.urban'
AFT[which((data$capital3+data$capital4)>=60)]<-'multi.mixed'
AFT[which(ata$capital4>70)]<-'multi.nb'
```

Comment: Thank you @Dave2e for this advice! I've worked on replacing the loop based on your suggestions and as you say it's so much faster and negates the need for a progress bar.